# Doctrine ORM insert auto increment ID to other column on same insert

Tags: doctrine-orm, orm, symfony-3.4

In my table the id is auto increment. And cid and dsid can not be NULL. On insert i need somehow to insert in dsid the value of the auto increment cid. How can i manage this in doctrine ORM / Symfony?

Table:

```
--------------------------------------
cid | dsid | lid
--------------------------------------
```

Entity:

```
 /**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="CID", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $cid;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="DSID", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $dsid;

/**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="LID", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $lid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Id generation takes place on database side during inserting, it has nothing to do with Doctrine. You can implement trigger on database side. or make fields nullable to insert a record, and then have postFlush event that will set those fields equal to ID.

Comment: Thanks. I created a Event Listeners to take care of this.